# change web directory for specific urls

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, symfony1, redirect, http-redirect

We have right now our frontend web site on symfony 1.4 we are looking for possibility to have symfony 3 for specific frontend urls for example http://staging.viventura.de/reisen/peru or http://staging.viventura.de/reisen/peru/xpbc

Is There a possibility to change web directory from htaccess file in order to certain urls goes to another web directory?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the apache [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/fr/mod/mod_alias.html).

```
ServerName staging.viventura.de
DocumentRoot /var/www/sf-1/web
Alias /reisen/peru /var/www/sf-3/web
Alias /reisen/peru/xpbc /var/www/sf-3/web
```

Assuming the main project on Symfony1 location is `/var/www/sf-1`,
and that the Symfony3 is `/var/www/sf-3`.

*Note:* Not allowed in `.htaccess`, only in `httpd|apache2|[vhostname].conf` config files.

Comment: Hi Chalasr, First of all thanks for you answer, the big issue now is that we have a managed server so we can't change any settings file, do you know if there is a possibility to do it from htaccess file? Thanks

Comment: You can use apache mod_rewrite to make some redirection rules from the `.htaccess` . I hope you can make it works.

Comment: Not sure what sort of administration capabilities you have, but a symbolic link should accomplish this as well if you have SSH access.

Comment: What do you mean by a symbolic link ? The application is pointed by a hard-defined `DocumentRoot` that points to a front-controller with the help of a `.htaccess`. How a symbolic link can help ? All is URL rewriting and dynamic routing in Symfony, there is not any kind of physically existing directories that would correspond to a part of the URL. One of the applications must win if you doesn't define any alias or rewrite rule that make the directory served by apache is not the DocumentRoot, depending on one or several specific URIs .